# How to forward a request using a URL string in Symfony2

Tags: php, model-view-controller, symfony, routes

I want to perform a sub-request, but don't have the route in the format $this->forward() expects - I only have the url as a string.

```
// Symfony2 wants...
$this->forward('ProjectCustomerBundle:Customer:view', array('id' => 1234));

// I want... 
$this->forward('customer/view/1234');
```

Surely I can manually build a Route or Request object from the url to achieve this? I've got a sneaky suspicion that I'm missing something obvious here...

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Use `$this->get('router')->match('customer/view/1234')` and you should get an array with `_controller` value and all other route parameters you need to pass.

Answer (score 0):

https://github.com/Cosmologist/SymfonyCommonBundle#routing-utils

```
return $this->httpKernel->handle(Request::create($uri), HttpKernelInterface::SUB_REQUEST);
```

Comment: What’s that supposed to be? Can you please provide more details on how this answers the question?

Comment: more details? read this very complexity code block :D

1. get http_kernel service
2. create request by you url - Request::create($uri)
3. call $httpKernel->handle($request, , HttpKernelInterface::SUB_REQUEST)

and this will make forward to URL

Comment: How does the link you’ve posted relate to the code below? I don’t see what they might have in common. The code is using Symfony core features, while the link promotes an unrelated package/bundle of yours.

Comment: Are you serious?
The bundle contains utils for symfony. You can use this bundle to avoid copying this code.

Mathew wants to do
$this->forward('customer/view/1234')
You can use RoutingUtils::forwardToUri('customer/view/1234')

The body of the method is
return $this->httpKernel->handle(Request::create($uri), HttpKernelInterface::SUB_REQUEST);

You ask very strange questions.